# Quantum GIS Installation Failure

Tags: qgis, installation

I installed GSL 1.16 & GDAL 1.10, then I proceed to install QGIS 1.8.0

After running the .pkg(installer) I get the following message.

---

Failure 
The GDAL 1.9 framework is required.

---

Does this mean I should be using GDAL 1.9 instead of 1.10 or is it just not recognizing 1.10?

Answer (score 2):

Quantum GIS 1.8 needs GDAL 1.9 and doesn't work with DGAL 1.10.

nice regards,
Jörn

Comment: Please explain your answer in detail including additional references,hardware/software requirement

Comment: That's a bit harsh! Jorn appears to have answered Tor's question by stating he needs 1.9 not 1.10 - there was no mention in the original post about the hardware - and Tor appears to have just needed confirmation that 1.9 was needed to install QGIS 1.8.